# How to embed a tweet from Twitter which is also AMP valid?

Tags: twitter, amp-html

I want to embed a tweet from Twitter in my WordPress blog. I recently made the AMP version of the website.

But, the embed codes for AMP and non-AMP pages are different. But, I have one post editor at WordPress for both versions of the website. How to achieve this thing?

Comment: You can use "amp-twitter" module of AMP for this. Please, refer to this link for details. https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-twitter/

Answer (score 1):

Check this [guide out](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/third_party_components). The first example is exactly how to embed Tweets.

You need to embed the library on your page:

```
<script async custom-element="amp-twitter"
  src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-twitter-0.1.js"></script>
```

Then, you can add as many tweets as you want. Just change the attribute: data-tweetid for the id of the tweet to embed.

```
<amp-twitter width="390" height="50"
    layout="responsive"
    data-tweetid="638793490521001985">
</amp-twitter>
```

See a [github example](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/examples/twitter.amp.html).

PS: If you do not like how it works, you can always [use an iframe](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/iframes) and then use another HTML page to do whatever you want there; but I would definitely encourage you to use the library that AMP provides.